# Enqueuing scripts and styles in custom plugins

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I have a couple of questions regarding enqueuing scripts and styles in custom plugin code.

I've recently come across plugin code where scripts were enqueued hooing into the `template_redirect` action hook while scripts were enqueued using the `ss_css` (I guess this is a custom action) and `login_enqueue_scripts` action hooks.

My question, therefore, is:

What is the most appropriate hook to enqueue JS scripts and styles. Is it `wp_enqueue_scripts` as is the case in themes? Or should it be more purpose specific as in the scenario described above? In short, should enqueuing scripts and styles in plugins be governed by different rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Straight outta the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts):

> `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.

So the simple answer to your question is yes, `wp_enqueue_scripts` is always the correct action for enqueuing scripts AND styles. This is so other themes/plugins can modify previously-enqueued files or other plugins (e.g. a minifier) can assume that all scripts/styles are loaded with that hook.